# how to expand INTENT cards in debug view?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Is there a way to make the "INTENT" and "DETAILS" cards in Debug console expand? Frequently the info is truncated.  It seems like these should be clickable.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the intent, put mouse over the intent, the full NL utterance or intent will show in pop-up window.

To copy-past the NL utterance or intent, use the debugger window, please see screenshot as attached. The right side panel of simulator window is just a brief summary of each step, please use the debugger window if you need additional information like the actions taken, results returned, or in this case, the NL utterance or the aligned NL interpretation. 
[image]